# Chrome Dev Tool > Coverage > css showing 100% unused but actually used

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, code-coverage

I am using chrome dev tool in localhost using IIS. There is a file app.css that is showing on the coverage tool as 100% unused (in sources) but when I see in the Elements tab, the style is being used on the page. On the Network Tab I removed the cache. Does this tool not work in localhost?

Here it is showing that this part of the code is unused
[image: Here it is showing that this part of the code is unused]

---

On the Elements tab it is actually being used:
[image: On the Elements tab it is actually being used]

Comment: having issues as well. Any updates?